# Magento 2 : How to Remove Encryption key from URL

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to get rid of URL encryption key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove encryption key from admin panel URLs, then follow below process:

- Login to **admin panel** and go to **`Stores`** -> **`Configuration`**.
- Under **`Advanced`** section, click on **`Admin`** tab.
- Under **`Security`** subsection, change the value of **`Add Secret Key to URLs`** to **`No`**.
- Click on **`Save Config`** button to save the configuration.

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Thanks Mohit... that worked... Don't know how did i miss this.